# What do you call a set whose subsets all have unique sums?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, combinations

An example would be $\{1, 3, 7\}$, which has subsets with sums $1, 3, 7, 4, 10, 8, 11$.

What is this called?

Comment: I don't know of a special name, but [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v5i1r3/pdf) is a reference.

Comment: @amWhy thanks, I edited.

Comment: If one only demands that the *pairwise* sums are distinct, then this would be a Sidon set. But I know that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are usually called [sets with distinct subset sums](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums). The name is a little long, but is self-descriptive, which is a plus. Sometimes it gets shortened to subset-sum-distinct set, or SSD-set. Like in the paper *On subset-sum-distinct sequences* by Jaegug Bae.

[image: ssd]

Comment: The link unfortunately gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error.