# Set of positive integers with unique sums

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

What I'm looking for is the **name** of a type of number set. Given a number ***T*** (for total) and a set of positive integers ***S***, I want to uniquely identify the subset of ***S*** that sums to ***T***. All sets containing 1 or 2 positive integers will pass the test, since there is a unique combination of those numbers and the sum will therefore be the same.

For example:

**{1, 7, 89}** passes the test. Any combination of those numbers, when summed, will generate a unique ***T***, and vice versa, any ***T*** that is a sum of a combination of those numbers will generate a unique subset of ***S***. So, the set of all ***T*** s for the above set is {0, 1, 7, 8, 89, 90, 96, 97}.

**{2, 3, 7, 8}** **does not** pass the test. There are multiple combinations that yield a total of 10 ({2, 8}, and {3, 7}). So if I specified a ***T*** of 10, you could not tell me with confidence the combination that produced that sum.

With that out of the way. **My question is this... Is there name for a set of positive integers like this?** I'd like to learn more about them more a personal project of mine.

Comment: try the powers of 2

Comment: [What do you call a set whose subsets all have unique sums?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879865/what-do-you-call-a-set-whose-subsets-all-have-unique-sums) is a similar question. [Greg Martin's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879865/what-do-you-call-a-set-whose-subsets-all-have-unique-sums#comment1815649_879865) mentions [Sidon sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence), which seems like what you're looking for, since your examples only require unique sums for each two integers.

Comment: @kate I'd say that post answers my question pretty well! I don't want to limit myself to summing two integers (in the case of Sidon sets), but if you post an answer with a link to that post, I'll confirm it for you. =)

Comment: it looks like a general case of [sumfree sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-free_set) problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [sets with distinct subset sums](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums).

Comment: Curious if there's an algorithm to generate these (or really, just a list for different set size n?  I have a very unique use case for them in combinatorial optimization.  I have hand-written a set of size 7 but would like to have a way to create/lookup a set of size n.

Comment: They can easily be generated by picking a number that is greater than the sum of the previously chosen numbers, e.g. `{2, 12 (>2), 22 (>14), 40 (>36), 78 (>76)}`.

Comment: The most compact lists will contain *differences* of the numbers from the Conway-Guy sequence as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079473/is-the-conway-guy-sequence-actually-subset-sum-distinct).