# Is the Conway-Guy sequence actually subset-sum-distinct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory

As I understand it, the Conway-Guy Sequence is a set of integers with distinct subset sums.

Here are the first 5 integers in the series:

$$
A = \{1, 2, 4, 7, 13\}
$$

But, clearly, a subset $B$ is in conflict with a subset $C$:

\begin{align}
B &= \{1, 2, 4, 7\} \\
C &= \{1, 13\} \\
\end{align}
$$
\operatorname{sum}(C) = \operatorname{sum}(B) = 14
$$
Am I understanding the sequence wrong? If not, what exactly would a set of numbers with all possible subsets having unique sums be called?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for reformatting my comment to better suit Math Stack Exchange! My head was still stuck on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://oeis.org/A005318. The claim is not that the numbers themselves have distinct subset sums. It is that for any $k$, the set of differences between the $k^{th}$ number in the sequence and the numbers before it all have distinct subset sums. For example, since the first $6$ entries are $0,1,2,4,7,13$, this means that the set of $5$ numbers
$$
\{13-0,13-1,13-2,13-4,13-7\}=\{6, 9, 11, 12, 13\}
$$
should have subset distinct sums.